Outlook appointment page not refreshing to display modified content on Send Receive All
I have outlook plugin which is developed using MAPI C++ with interacts with out server using SOAP.
The scenario is something like below.
user2 shares his calendar with user2 with admin rights. Now user1's profile is configured on Outlook.
Now user2 creates some appointment using web browser and that appointment gets synced to Outlook and shows in user1's profile inside user2 calendar.
Now when user2 modifies/updates subject or description(body) of the same appointment from Web browser, and user1 clicks send receive all on outlook, the calendar preview does reflect the modified subject and body however opening the appointment page, shows old content. While debugging the code I have observed that my MAPI code perfectly sets below property with updated/modified contents.
I am using Outlook 365
PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC_W
PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT_W
PR_SUBJECT_W
PR_BODY_W
PR_HTML


Now when I close the outlook and open it again, it shows the updated/modified content perfectly on appointment page as well.
It is something to do with main page not being refreshed or anything I can do so that it reflects the updated content there only without restarting it?
Please see below screen to understand it more. Any help would be much appreciated.


I checked the return value while updating above properties and it returns success every time.

Outlook likes caching last opened items, appointments even more than regular mail items. For regular messages, opening another message and then opening the original one, forces a refresh. For the appointments, it is sometimes necessary to go to another folder, open another appointment, go back, and open the original. Is that the case?
Not much you can do about that.

Hi Dmitry, Thanks for your response. Yes, I tried to open another folder and then again open appointment and all this things, but still no success. Once again thank you for that as well.

Is the appointment referenced in your code or some other addin? Outlook will hold on to the stale data for as long as the corresponding item is referenced by its UI or the Object Model.

We just update the above properties and then release the appointment. Still just for that matter, if I want to check, If Outlook has hold the stale data for that meeting, how can I check that? Or Is there a way to refresh it from our side?

There is no way to check if an item is cached and there is no way to refresh it. Do you use Outlook Object Model in your code at all?
